# What APIs are required along with OCP CronJob

Tags: kubernetes, openshift

I have ConfigMap, ImageStream, BuildConfig, DeploymentConfig APIs that successfully deploy my app and launch the number of pods as asked. But I want to use CronJob now.

Do I replace the DeploymentConfig completely? Because the idea is to launch a new pod according to a corn expression that is passed into the CronJob API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, why not , you can reuse the template  section of your `DeploymentConfig`. For example:

```yaml
kind: "DeploymentConfig"
apiVersion: "v1"
metadata:
  name: "frontend"
spec:
  template: 
    metadata:
      labels:
        name: "frontend"
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: "helloworld"
          image: "openshift/origin-ruby-sample"
          ports:
            - containerPort: 8080
              protocol: "TCP"
  replicas: 5 
  triggers:
    - type: "ConfigChange" 
    - type: "ImageChange" 
      imageChangeParams:
        automatic: true
        containerNames:
          - "helloworld"
        from:
          kind: "ImageStreamTag"
          name: "origin-ruby-sample:latest"
  strategy: 
    type: "Rolling"
  paused: false 
  revisionHistoryLimit: 2 
  minReadySeconds: 0
```

would just become something like this :

```yaml
apiVersion: batch/v1beta1
kind: CronJob
metadata:
  name: frontend
spec:
  schedule: "*/1 * * * *"
  jobTemplate:
    spec:
      template:
        metadata:
          labels:
            name: "frontend"
        spec:
          containers:
            - name: "helloworld"
              image: "openshift/origin-ruby-sample"
              ports:
                - containerPort: 8080
                  protocol: "TCP"
          restartPolicy: OnFailure
```

✌️

Comment: Rico, so it means I won't need the `DeploymentCofing` at all. Coz I tried removing it while adding the `CronJob` and it failed, I am pretty sure I must have done something wrong. I just wanted to confirm that I was not on the wrong path. And do I not need a `Job` along with `CronJob` or is `CronJob` independent of `Job`? Appreciate your help.

Comment: Correct, you don't need the DeploymentConfig

Comment: Rico, what about `Job`? Do I require `Job` in order to `CronJob` to function? Or, is `CronJob` self-sufficient?

Comment: A cronjob is a superset of job basically, a cronjob runs a one time job.

Answer (score 0):

> Do I replace the DeploymentConfig completely? Because the idea is to
> launch a new pod according to a corn expression that is passed into
> the CronJob API.

I don't think so. Basically, "DeploymentConfig" is for running "Pod", "CronJob" is for running one-off "Pod" based on "Job". So their use cases are different each other.

For example, "DeploymentConfig" have a feature which trigger based on image changes through "ImageStream", this is required the target pod should run, not one-off one. It's not available to "CronJob".

But if you just want to use "CronJob" for the pod deployment instead of "DeploymentConfig" without image triggering feature, you should also consider how to refer the "ImageStream" on the "CronJob". Because "CronJob" is a native Kubernetes resource, so "CronJob" cannot use directly "ImageStream".
Add "alpha.image.policy.openshift.io/resolve-names: '*'" annotation to "CronJob" as follows for that. Refer [Using Image Streams with Kubernetes Resources](https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/3.11/dev_guide/managing_images.html#using-is-with-k8s) for more details.

e.g.>

```
apiVersion: batch/v1beta1
kind: CronJob
metadata:
  name: pi
spec:
  schedule: "*/1 * * * *"  
  jobTemplate:             
    spec:
      template:
        metadata:
          annotations:
            alpha.image.policy.openshift.io/resolve-names: '*'  <-- You need this for using ImageStream
          labels:          
            parent: "cronjobpi"
        spec:
          containers:
          - name: pi
            image: "<ImageStream name>"
            command: ["perl",  "-Mbignum=bpi", "-wle", "print bpi(2000)"]
          restartPolicy: OnFailure
```

But if you don't care to use ImageStream, you can deploy the same template for containers of the pod between "DeploymentConfig" and "CronJob" as Rico mentioned. I hope if help you. :)

Comment: Daein, when you say "...based on Job...". Do I need to define a `Job` as well while defining a `CronJob`? And, I don't need a running pod all the time so does that mean I do should remove the `DeploymentConfig`? I just need to run 'one-off pod' like you said, I think I need a `Job` defined as well.

Comment: I mean "CronJob" create Pod through "Job" which is created by the "CronJob". And if your use case is one-off Pod, then you need not to use "DeploymentConfig".

Comment: Got it Daein. and you understood my use case correctly. I will not use `DeploymentConfig` and use `CronJob`. Only thing I am still confused is - do i need both `Job` and `CronJob` or is `CronJob` self sufficient?

Comment: You just need to create only "CronJob" for your use case without creating "Job". Because "CronJob" is used to control the "Job" automatically.